# Error in pom.xml in Eclipse Code Recommenders Source

Tags: xml, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I am getting this error message in  tag in almost every pom.xml file.

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-
 plugin:0.20.0:build-qualifier (execution: default-build-qualifier, phase: validate)
- Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-
 plugin:0.20.0:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)
- maven-enforcer-plugin (goal "enforce") is ignored by m2e.
- Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-
 plugin:0.20.0:validate-version (execution: default-validate-version, phase: validate)
- Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-
 plugin:0.20.0:validate-id (execution: default-validate-id, phase: validate)
```

i imported the source code into eclipse using Maven/existing maven project.
i also set target platform as eclipse keplar.
But this error persists.
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

For the records: This question has been posted in the recommenders-dev mailing list also.

See [1] for an explanation. You may also use Eclipse Oomph to setup Code Recommenders in your IDE. This is described in this thread [2].

[1] https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/recommenders-dev/msg01690.html

[2] https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/recommenders-dev/msg01683.html